# How to declare string variable?

Tags: php

The first appearance to this variable $totpro in my code is this way

```
$totpro = $totpro + $row['profitloss'];
```

I want to use it to sum all profits, however, I receive this warning message on running

> Warning: Undefined variable $totpro

but if I put this code before the previous code it runs with no problems

```
$totpro = "0";
```

I don't like using that code to declare the function, it tried

```
String $totpro
```

but unexpectedly it didn't work. Now tell me how to define $totpro without to have to use $totpro = "0";

Comment: If the first appearance of the variable is `$totpro = $totpro + ...`, then what does `$totpro` on the right hand side refer to…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are summing numbers, the initial declaration should set the value to 0 (i.e. a number):

```
$totpro = 0;
```

You tried `"0"`, which is a string. Technically this will work, but it is not the best way.